# Passing a PHP variable to a java-script function

Tags: php, javascript, html

im trying to pass a value to a java-script function. but when i click the link i get a 

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

here is the code

```
<?php 

  include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
  $routeHTML = '';

  $sql = "SELECT user,title FROM route";
  $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $title = $row["title"]; 
    $user = $row["user"];
    $routeHTML .= '<p>Planned By '.$user.'</p><a href="#" onclick="fetchdata('.$title.')" title="Load This Map">'.$title.'</a><br />';
  }
?>
```

i echo the `$routeHTML` in a div tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to add quotes for the javascript:

```
$routeHTML .= '<p>Planned By '.$user.'</p><a href="#" onclick="fetchdata(\''.$title.'\')" title="Load This Map">'.$title.'</a><br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to surround your string with a '' quotes like this...

```
$routeHTML .= '<p>Planned By '.$user.'</p><a href="#" onclick="fetchdata(\''.$title.'\')" title="Load This Map">'.$title.'</a><br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

The Parameter to your JS function is undefined (since the parsed HTML is missing quotes - JS assumes title is an undefined variable).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the quotes, do like this:

```
fetchdata(\''.$title.'\')
```

Otherwise php will not render the `'` properly and you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a php variable to a javascript function in this way:

```
<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="js_function('<?php echo $var; ?>')">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not recommended to make inline Js (as an attribute of the tag).

So, i encourage you to separate javascript from html code, like this :

Html:

```
$routeHtml = '<p>Planned By '.$user.'</p><a href="#" class="MyLink" data-title="'.$title.'" title="MyTitle">'.$title.'</a><br />';
```

Js (with jQuery, but also work for vanillaJs):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".MyLink").click(function(e){
        fetchData($(this).data("title"))
    });
});
```

Note the `data-title` attribute, the `data-*` attributes are intended to store custom data, so it's a great way to exchange informations between php and Javascript inside templates.

More info about data-* attributes : http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/